# Should a house wall be perpendicular to the direction of a strong wind carrying rain water?

Tags: structures, photovoltaics, wind

I am building a perfectly squared single-storey house (10m x 10m).
To have the best output from the solar panels, which should face South as straight as possible, the external South facing wall of the house will be perpendicular to the South.
However, that would mean that the West wall would be facing directly (90 degrees) the strong wet wind travelling from the West to the East in my region.
Do you think, to minimise the amount of wall surface that gets wet due to the West wind, it would be better to avoid that and tilt the house a little bit towards the South-South-East? If yes, how many degrees should it be tilted by?
The maximum output from the solar panels is the most essential bit. However, if by changing the position of the house by a couple of degrees I do not lose too much of the solar panel output but gain a significant improvement in the level of dryness of the walls, that could be an acceptable compromise.
As a side note the roof of the house will be a hip type one, with 4 faces covering the top of the house all over - not an open gable/2 faces type one which would have an extended upper part of the West facing wall exposed to the rain-carrying wind.
Thank you.

Comment: I have never heard of building a house based on wind direction due to rain; waterproof your walls

Comment: What makes you think that the West Wind comes exactly from the west in your location? Local winds follow ground contours. and also contain rotations.

Comment: Energy vs longevity- isn't the whole point of a solar panel to get energy while expending life of panels? Solar panels are expensive compared to waterproofing.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and help. I will have the South wall face the South perpendicularly and make sure my walls are waterproof.